# Use $not or $ne in update query

Tags: mongodb, updates

Should I use `$not` or `$ne` in the query:

```
Mytable.update({ TheThing: Thing, 
  'UpdatedInfo.NewInfo': {$ne: ThisNewestInfo} }, {
    $push: {
      UpdatedInfo: {
        TheDate: ThisDate,
        NewInfo: ThisNewestInfo,
        Past: OriginalInfo
      }
    }
},
function (err, result) {
  if (err){
    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
}
```

If I `only` want to update the document when `ThisNewestInfo` is **not** already present in `UpdatedInfo` array, in `NewInfo` object element. Trying to understand the difference between `$not` and `$ne`.

And also:
If the document does not contain `UpdatedInfo`field in the beginning? How should I change the update query above? Meaning that if `UpdatedInfo`does not exists it adds `UpdatedInfo`, and later on, say next day, checks if `ThisNewestInfo`is not already present when updating document again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your collection actually.

The main different between *$ne* and *$not* in this scenario is that, *$not* performs a **logical disjunction**. That is if your document didn't had an `UpdatedInfo` field, using $not would have pushed the document while using *$ne* nothing would have happened to that document.

So if all your document of collection has `UpdatedInfo` field, its better to go with *$ne*.

**Edit**

Based on your edit you mentioned UpdatedInfo might not be present in document. In such cases you should use $not. $ne wont be able to update docs that doesn't have UpdatedInfo field.

Remember like this: $not checks for presence of key as well as value, while $ne checks only for value and ignores document that doesn't have the particular key in query.

Comment: But if the document does not contain `UpdatedInfo` field in the beginning? It is what the update query above does, meaning that if `UpdatedInfo` does not exists it adds `UpdatedInfo`, and later on, say next day, checks if `ThisNewestInfo` is not already present when updating document again.

Comment: Ok thanks, but could I change query above to account for if `UpdatedInfo` is not present first, and then if it is present, update only if `ThisNewestInfo` is not present already. But the thing is that `UpdatedInfo` is "present" in the beginning but without any array elements.

Comment: do you want to update by existence of field rather than value of field?

Comment: I want to add an object to `UpdatedInfo` the first time if `UpdatedInfo` is empty. And later on only update `UpdatedInfo` if `ThisNewestInfo` is not already present in `UpdatedInfo`. How should you do such a query?:)

Comment: $push creates a new field if the field is absent ?

Comment: Sure it does. The query you posted will work for your use case (equality conditions). In such case both $ne and $not: {$eq: xxx} will work in same way. In case of performing logical conditionals like $le, $gt, etc. better stick to $not. In short for your use case you may go with any of the two operator.

Comment: So I can keep the query as it is you mean?:)